# how to create a trampoline function using DetourAttachEx? (with MS detours)

Tags: c++, c, hook, detours

I have a dll and i wish to create a detour to one of its exported functions,

- The dll is not part of windows.
- I need to be able to call the real function after my detour (call the real function from a detoured one)
- I know the exact signature of the function.
- I already have been able to detour the function, but right now i can't call the real one.

I realize i need to use a trampoline function, I've seen examples online.
the problem is: all those examples show how to detour a windows API function, i need to do the same for a function i get thorough a dll import.

any help would be welcomed

--edit
just to clarify, I have attempted to call the original function by its pointer, but that does not work.
also tried using the method from this stack overflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496734/need-to-call-original-function-from-detoured-function)

that doesn't even crash but it looks like it goes into to an infinite loop (i assume because in the original function there is a jump to the detoured one)

edit -- solved!
not sure what solved it,
used [this](https://trac.netvor.sk/umage/browser/dllinject/dll/hook.cpp?rev=27&order=date) as reference.

- stopped using getProcadder and instead started using DetourFindFunction instead
- cleaned up the code (pretty sure i cleaned out whatever caused the issue)

works,
thanks anyway

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by a detour. Also I must admit I've never heard the term "Trampoline function" in over a decade as a professional software engineer. If you are simply trying to call a function in a third party DLL from your code, then the first thing you need to state is whether you have a header file, a LIB file, and whether it is an OLE/COM/CLR DLL or not.

Comment: Ok, I read up on Google about Detours and OMG what a load of horribleness. I can't believe someone (Microsoft?) actually wrote a library for that? What use is it apart from A) attaching viruses to programs, and B) Hacking into Windows to try and override its normal behaviour because Microsoft don't give you any chance of doing it in any normal way? What exactly are you trying to achieve? From what I read it should make no difference where the function comes from. What is going wrong for you exactly?

Comment: most people simply use it for debugging and logging. I'm trying to filter one of the functions of that dll.

Comment: @AlistairG: they have many uses, many of them are malicious or with devious intentions and the sheer fact that the 64bit detours library costs $$$ indicates that. heck, MS themselves use it(generic function hooking, not the Detours lib) in a fashion, its called hot-patching.

Comment: Is this the same as *function interpositioning* ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't use detours(I actually detest it!), but detouring any non hot-patchable function can be done in a generic manner, like so:

Sstep 1:
insert a `JMP <your code>` at the start of the function, takes 5 bytes, probably a little more to align to the nearest instruction. as an example

the start of the function to hook:

```
SUB ESP,3C
PUSH EDI
PUSH ESI
//more code
```

would become:

```
JMP MyFunction
//more code
```

one would do this by writing `0xE9` at the first byte then writing the value `(function_addr - patch_addr + sizeof(INT_PTR))` in the following DWORD. writing should be done using `WriteProcessMemory` after setting Read/write/execute permissions with `VirtualProtectEx`

Step 2:
next, we create an assembly interface:

```
void __declspec(naked) MyFunc()
{

    __asm
    {
        call Check             ;call out filter func
        test eax,eax           ; test if we let the call through
        je _EXIT
        sub esp,3c             ; its gone through, so we replicate what we overwrote
        push edi
        push esi
        jmp NextExecutionAddress ; now we jump back to the location just after our jump
    _EXIT:
        retn                   ; note, this must have the correct stack cleanup
    }

}
```

NextExecutionAddress will need to be filled at run time using `ModuleBase + RVA`.

---

To be honest, its way easier, and better(!) to just EAT (Export Address Table) hook the export table of the dll, or IAT (Import Address Table) hook the import tables of whats calling the funcs you want to filter. Detours should have functions for these type of hooks, if not, there are other freely available libs to do it.

The other way would be to use detour to hook every call in the apps using the dll to reroute them to a proxy function in your own code, this has the advantage of allowing one to filter only certain calls, and not everything across a binary(it is possible to do the same using `_ReturnAddress`, but thats more work), the disadvantage though is capturing the locations to patch(I use ollydbg + a custom patching engine) and it won't work on non-regular calling convention functions(like those made with `#pragma aux` in Watcom or the optimized calls generated by VC7+).

One important thing to note: if your hooking a multithreaded app, your patches need to be done with the app suspended, or be done attomically use `InterlockedExchange`, `InterlockExchange64` and `InterlockedExchangePointer`(I use the latter for all IAT/EAT hooks, especially when hooking from a 'third party process')

---

Looking at the post you link to, the method there is horrible in my opinion, mainly due to the assmebly :P but, how are you calling this pointer you obtain, and how is it obtained?

Comment: it's obtained through GetProcAddress, its the first paramater of DetourAttach. i keep the old pointer in a global function pointer

Comment: @user527744: sounds like your creating an infinite loop because the pointer returned by `DetourAttach` is to the address where the detour begins, see my example above, should be pretty clear how that happens :)

Comment: when i first started my project I though of implementing something similar to what you suggested, however I decided not to use such an approach because: a. its dangerous to write directly into assembly b. it would be difficult to do with a multi threaded process c. i was afraid of x64 and how it would affect the size of Assembly commands. thanks for your answer, but the answer i'm looking for is one that uses detours api (or something like it)

Comment: @user527744: the second section of my answer can be used, Detours should have EAT/IAT hooking, if not you can still using its patching, you just need to scan the thunks yourself